# linux - watch command shows colors only on some systems

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, watch

I am trying to make `watch` command show colors of text.

the thing is, I am able to make it show color on my machine with this command:

```
watch -c "some file"
```

But on another server, it doesn't work.

I tried to use `CF_COLOR=force` and `CF_COLOR=true`, no change.

So I figured that my `watch` version is an updated one compared to the server's version.

**server version:** watch from procps-ng 3.3.9

**my version:** watch from procps-ng 3.3.10

I tried to look up when did they add the `-c` option for colors, didn't find a specification of on what version is was added.

Could it be because of other things beside the `watch` version? I do know that the server is able to show colors because it does show colors without the `watch` command.

What am I missing?

Comment: let me guess, you connect to the server using ssh?

Comment: What operating systems are the servers running? How do you connect to each server? What is the output of `echo $TERM` on each server? How exactly are you watching a *file*? Do you mean `watch -c "cat file"`? Is there any particular reason you're not using `tail -f file` instead?

Comment: I am connecting with SSH to the server. does that cause a problem? the $TERM value is "xterm-256color" on both my machine and the server. my OS is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and the server is Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. I am watching the file like this "watch -c -n 1 (script name)". the script print the text with the colors

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk is connecting via SSH the reason I don't see the colors ? is there a fix for that?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16336/how-to-get-coloured-terminal-over-ssh